# Can't register property group

Tags: python, add-on, properties

I'm having a bit of a weird situation. I have one Property Group which I am successfully registering, and another seemingly identical one that fails to register. I have no idea why.

These are my two Property Groups - the `Shared` one is working, but the `UiState` isn't.

```
class Props:

    class UiState(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
        """These props are just used for temporary UI state"""
        prompt_to_restart_blender : bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Finished Syncing Presets", default=False)

    class Shared(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
        """These are normal global properties"""
        default_wall_height : bpy.props.FloatProperty(name= "Default Height (feet)", soft_min=0,soft_max=10,  default=8)
        wall_dimension_format : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
            name="Wall Dimension Format",
            description="What is the text format of wall measurements?",
            items={
                ("FEET_AND_INCHES", "feet_and_inches", "Feet & Inches"),
                ("INCHES", "inches", "Inches")
            },
            default="FEET_AND_INCHES"
        )
```

As you can see here, I am registering these in the same way:

```
def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.shared_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Props.Shared)
    bpy.types.Scene.ui_state_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Props.UiState)
```

I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: PointerProperty(...) expected an RNA type, failed with: RuntimeError: , missing bl_rna attribute from 'RNAMetaPropGroup' instance (may not be registered)

[traceback elided]

> bpy.types.Scene.ui_state_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Props.UiState)                                      ValueError: bpy_struct "Scene" registration error: ui_state_props could not register

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MartyFouts Ahh thanks

Comment: Feel free to leave an answer saying that I forgot to register it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the first line of the error message:

> TypeError: PointerProperty(...) expected an RNA type, failed with: RuntimeError: , missing bl_rna attribute from 'RNAMetaPropGroup' instance (may not be registered)

You have to register before you can assign it as a pointer property

Comment: >>> bpy.utils.register_class(PointerProperty)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: register_class(...): expected a class argument, not 'builtin_function_or_method'